# How to make golden tests with fonts well rendered in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

What are the steps to take to have images rendered without the default squares-only font "Ahem" of Flutter's tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

Create `test/flutter_test_config.dart` with:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:golden_toolkit/golden_toolkit.dart';

Future<void> testExecutable(FutureOr<void> Function() testMain) async {
  return GoldenToolkit.runWithConfiguration(
    () async {
      await loadAppFonts();
      await testMain();
    },
    config: GoldenToolkitConfiguration(
      // Currently, goldens are not generated/validated in CI for this repo. We have settled on the goldens for this package
      // being captured/validated by developers running on MacOSX. We may revisit this in the future if there is a reason to invest
      // in more sophistication
      skipGoldenAssertion: () => !Platform.isMacOS,
    ),
  );
}
```

Include in `pubspec.yaml`:

```
dev_dependencies:
  golden_toolkit: ^0.7.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/images/

  fonts:
    - family: Roboto
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf
```

Create the dirs: `mkdir assets/{images,fonts}` and download [Roboto font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto) into fonts dir

Make sure to have that maybe empty [images dir created](https://github.com/eBay/flutter_glove_box/issues/31#issuecomment-598420555)